# Finding largest product in c#

Tags: c#

Currently I am trying to find the thirteen adjacent digits in a 1000-digit number that will have the greatest product.Now I written a function which is supposed to multiply the desired number of adjacent digits to be multiplied and later store  the product  in a list . The two parameters the functions takes are the desired number of adjacent digits and string which contains the number. But for some reason it wont stop running.

```
    public static void giveProduct(int quantity, string word)
    {
        int product = 1;
        int place1 = 0;
        int place2 = quantity - 1;
        int temp = 1;
        string temp2;

        while (place2 < word.Length)
        {
            for (int i = place1; i < place2; i++)
            {
                temp2 = word[i].ToString();
                temp = Int32.Parse(temp2);
                product = product * i;

            }

            products.Add(product);
            product = 1;
            place1 += quantity;
            place2 += quantity;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @rboe Why would that happen if quantity is `1`?

Comment: Your program does not do what is intended to be. Take the number 1234567 and the quantity 3. Then you check 123 and 456, but will never find the correct answer 567. And you never use temp; it should be product = product * temp.

Comment: @InBetween - you are right - it was too early in the morning for my comment.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: @Nebr So for example if the number was 123456789 and the quantity is 3, instead of it being 123, 456, 789, it would be 123, 234, 345, 456, 567, etc?

Comment: You could break the program and check the position of the debugger. I don't see a reason for this loop not terminating except if quantity is less than 1.

Comment: Well I tested it with a quantity of 4 and it does not terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't reproduce your issue, the method terminates "correctly" for any sensible input.

But anyway, that is far from the only issue in your implementation. Your method is not calculating correctly the maximum product because you are skipping through the string `quantity` characters at a time. You should be skipping *one* character at a time and taking the `quantity` long substring starting at that position.

For string `123456` and quantity `3` you are evaluating `123` and `456`. You should be checking `123`, `234`, `345`, etc.

Also, get into the habit of:

1. Validating inputs
2. Writing helper methods. The shorter a method, the harder to introduce a bug in it.
3. Consider all possible values that `word` can represent? Have you considered `{   1234 }`? (note the leading and trailing spaces). How about `-1234`?
4. Prepare for the worse. Make your code robust so its able to handle incorrect data; your program will crash if the input is `123$5`.

With all that in mind, consider the following implementation:

1. First a simple helper method that evaluates the product of *all* the digits of a given string representing a number.

   ```
   private static bool TryMultiplyDigits(string number, out int product)
   {
       Debug.Assert(number != null && number.Length > 0);
       product = 1;

       foreach (var c in number)
       {
           int digit;

           if (int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out digit))
           {
               product *= digit;
           }
           else
               return false;
       }

       return true;
   }
   ```

   Ok great, this method will give us the correct product or simply tell us it can't evaluate it for any input.
2. Now, a method that will create all the possible subtrings and return the maximum product found:

   ```
   public static int GetMaximumProduct(string number, int quantity)
   {
       if (number == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(number));

       if (quantity < 1)
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(quantity));

       if (quantity > number.Length)
           throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(quantity)} can not be greater than the length of {nameof(number)}.");

       var normalizedNumber = number.Trim();
       normalizedNumber = normalizedNumber.StartsWith("-") ? normalizedNumber.Substring(1) : normalizedNumber;

       if (string.IsEmpty(normalizedNumber))
       {
            product = 0;
            return true;
       }

       var maximumProduct = 0;

       for (var i = 0; i < normalizedNumber.Length - (quantity - 1); i++)
       {
           int currentProduct;
           if (TryMultiplyDigits(normalizedNumber.Substring(i, quantity), out currentProduct))
           {
               if (currentProduct > maximumProduct)
               {
                   maximumProduct = currentProduct;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               throw new FormatException("Specified number does not have the correct format.");
           }
       }

       return maximumProduct;
   }
   ```

And we're done!

Comment: Now i can see clearly that I misunderstood the problem and was miscalculating the product, thanks.